# Restful API that calls python methods

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, tastypie

Django and related extensions such as DRF and Tastypie are great at creating a restful layer over a model. I have methods that I want to expose. This is more like what traditional web services used to do with wsdl. How can this be done using either DRF or Tastypie.

Eg
The endpoint for an algorithm with calls for methods like BuildModel, Classify. Similar to http://oryx.io/docs/index.html#API_Endpoint_Reference

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have few methods say method1() and method2(). I believe if they are available in views.py and you already created url routes for the same in urls.py.

Then you already exposed your APIs (though not RESTful at all) to ourter world.

But DRF and Tastypie gonna help you if you are going to create REST apis. In very simple terms REST apis allows you 4 CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete) on single URL.

Like for /users/ endpoint.

- HTTP GET: /users/ => will return all users entries
- HTTP POST: /users/
  => will create new user in system
- HTTP PUT: /users/1 => will update user with id 1 in system with given paramaeters
- HTTP Delete:
  /users/1/ => this will delete user 1